# How to add banners in sidebar of my theme

Tags: sidebar

I am new to word press. I need to add 2 banners in my right side bar. Could you help me?? How can I do it?? What is the code which I have to insert in a text widget? I am using zeesynergie theme. Please help me

Comment: Upload your images to media, and then get their url from media files by clicking over them. Insert the img tag with url as source in text widget.

Answer (score 0):

There can be various way to do it. If the banners would be static then the easiest way i see is to

First add the banner to be used in the media using the media uploader and then using the text widget add it to the sidebar using the ***img*** tag

Answer (score 0):

Upload your banner into Media Library. (Media>Add new)
When image is uploaded click on **Edit** link and you will find direct link to your image on the top right.

Then add this code into your text widget.

```
<a href="http://website-you-promote.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://your-image-direct-link.jpg" alt="Your Alt Name"></a>
```

Make sure to change link and image location, as well as alt name.

Comment: Great @user1991. I am glad that you manage to solve this. Please mark correct answer as accepted, and community will continue to support you if you care about their help. Cheers!